# How many ways to put $10$ distinguishable balls in $5$ identical boxes so that no box has more than $3$ balls?

Tags: combinatorics, balls-in-bins

As the title says, I was asked to count the number of ways one can put $10$ different balls inside $5$ identical boxes so that no box has more than $3$ balls. I am really confused by the restriction and I can't even compute the number without the restriction (It confuses me that the boxes can't be distinguished but the balls are). Any explanation is more than welcome.

Comment: First, to count where boxes can't be distinguished but balls can, see [Stirling numbers of the Second Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) and [Bell Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number).

Comment: As for your specific problem... I don't have a great suggestion that gives an immediate answer... but you should be able to either break into cases directly: (3+3+3+1+0, 3+3+2+1+1, etc...) or if you prefer, break into cases based on bad arrangements.  To count a specific case like 3+3+2+1+1... Choose the six elements used for the 3's (*they all need selecting simultaneously since we can't tell the boxes apart*).  Then, one of those elements chosen will be smallest.  Chose the other two that share a box with it from those remaining five.  Next, choose what goes in the box with two.

Comment: @JMoravitz Ah! thanks so much, I wasn't aware of these numbers. That solves the question without the restriction.

Comment: @Sak: I have greatly simplified the presentation by removing mention of the multinomial coefficient with which all beginners may not be familiar, and using only permutations instead. You might not have seen this comment which was put below my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unaware of any analytical approach to the problem.

The best that I can do is break down the distributions into cases, and enumerate each case.  In the discussion below, I will let $n_k$ denote the enumeration for Case $k$, for $k \in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

So, the final tally will be

$$N = n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + n_4 + n_5.$$

The balls are distinguishable, and the boxes are not distinguishable.  In the discussion below, I will examine various distributions.

---

$\underline{\text{Case 1}}$

Distribution is $3-3-3-1-0.$

Superficially, the enumeration is:

$$\binom{10}{3}\times \binom{7}{3} \times \binom{4}{3} \times \binom{1}{1} = \frac{(10)!}{(3!)^3}. \tag1 $$

However, consider the situation where

- Ball-10, Ball-9, Ball-8 comprise Group-1.
- Ball-7, Ball-6, Ball-5 comprise Group-2.
- Ball-4, Ball-3, Ball-2 comprise Group-3.

In (1) above, this particular grouping will be counted $(3!)$ times, rather than only being counted once.  This is because there are $(3!)$ ways that the creations of Group-1, Group-2, and Group-3 might have been ordered.

Further, this over-counting by a factor of $(3!)$ will apply regardless of which (distinguishable) balls are used to create Group-1, Group-2, and Group-3.

So, you have that

$$n_1 = \frac{(10)!}{(3!)^3} \times \frac{1}{3!} = 2800.$$

It is important to note that the **over-counting adjustment factor** was required specifically because some of the groups were the **same size**.

---

$\underline{\text{Case 2}}$

Distribution is $3-3-2-2-0.$

**Again**, superficially, the enumeration is:

$$\binom{10}{3}\times \binom{7}{3} \times \binom{4}{2} \times \binom{2}{2} = \frac{(10)!}{(3!)^2 \times (2!)^2}. \tag2 $$

In (2) above, you have two over-counting factors to consider.  The two groups of $3$ could have been arranged in $(2!)$ ways, and the two groups of $2$ could have been arranged in $(2!)$ ways.

So, you have that

$$n_2 = \frac{(10)!}{(3!)^2 \times (2!)^2} \times \frac{1}{(2!)^2} = 6300.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Case 3}}$

Distribution is $3-3-2-1-1.$

Again, superficially, the enumeration is:

$$\binom{10}{3}\times \binom{7}{3} \times \binom{4}{2} \times \binom{2}{1} \times \binom{1}{1} = \frac{(10)!}{(3!)^2 \times (2!)}. $$

Similar to the previous section, you have two groups of $3$ and two groups of $1$.

So, you have that

$$n_3 = \frac{(10)!}{(3!)^2 \times (2!)} \times \frac{1}{(2!)^2} = 12600.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Case 4}}$

Distribution is $3-2-2-2-1.$

Again, superficially, the enumeration is:

$$\binom{10}{3}\times \binom{7}{2} \times \binom{5}{2} \times \binom{3}{2} \times \binom{1}{1} = \frac{(10)!}{(3!) \times (2!)^3}. $$

You have three groups of $2$.

So, you have that

$$n_4 = \frac{(10)!}{(3!) \times (2!)^3} \times \frac{1}{(3!)} = 12600.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Case 5}}$

Distribution is $2-2-2-2-2.$

Again, superficially, the enumeration is:

$$\binom{10}{2}\times \binom{8}{2} \times \binom{6}{2} \times \binom{4}{2} \times \binom{2}{2} = \frac{(10)!}{(2!)^5}. $$

You have five groups of $2$.

So, you have that

$$n_5 = \frac{(10)!}{(2!)^5} \times \frac{1}{(5!)} = 945.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Final Enumeration}}$

$$N = n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + n_4 + n_5$$

$$= 2800 + 6300 + 12600 + 12600 + 945 = 35245.$$

Answer (score 2):

A comparison with distinct balls in *distinct boxes*$\;$ **vs**$\;$ *identical boxes* yields a simple transformation (although $5$ cases can't be avoided here)

For the pattern $3-3-3-1-0,\;$ for distinct balls to distinct boxes, we have the product of two factorials,

*[Fill Pattern]*$\times$*[permute Pattern]*$\;=  
\large\frac{10!}{3!3!3!1!0!}\cdot\frac{5!}{3!1!1!}$

**The simple transformation for identical boxes is to change the numerator of the second term to** $1$,
thus $\quad\large\frac{10}{3!3!3!1!0!}\cdot\frac{1}{3!1!1!}$

So we simply apply this transform to each allowable pattern, viz.

$3-3-3-1-0:\;\;\large\frac{10!}{3!3!3!1!0!}\cdot\frac{1}{3!1!1!}$

$3-3-2-2-0:\;\frac{10!}{3!3~2!2!0!}\cdot\frac1{2!2!1!}$

$3-3-2-1-1:\;\frac{10!}{3!3!2!1!1!}\cdot\frac{1}{2!1!2!}$

$3-2-2-2-1:\;\frac{10!}{3!2!2!2!1!}\cdot\frac1{1!3!1!}$

$2-2-2-2-2:\;\frac{10}{2!2!2!2!2!}\cdot\frac1{5!}$

Computing and adding up, the [answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%2810%21%29*%5B%283%213%213%213%21%29%5E-1+%2B%283%213%212%212%212%212%21%29%5E-1+%2B%283%213%212%212%212%21%29%5E-1+%2B%283%212%212%212%213%21%29%5E-1+%2B%282%212%212%212%212%215%21%29%5E-1%5D) is $\boxed{35245}$

Comment: @Sak: I have greatly simplified the presentation by removing mention of the multinomial coefficient with which all beginners may not be familiar, and using only permutations instead.

Comment: +1 (also) : "The simple transformation for identical boxes is to change the numerator of the second term to 1," : this is an elegant and incisive explanation.  One minor point.  To the best of my knowledge, since Sak didn't *register* for your answer by leaving a trailing comment, he would not have been flagged by your comment, following your answer.  So, to flag him, you would have had to leave a corresponding comment following his posting.

Comment: @user2661923: Thanks, I have posted the remark against the question, as suggested by you.